# DB2 - Inserting a timestamp operation result in a timestamp field

Tags: db2, insert, timestamp

I got a some javascript Dojo code assembling a query from JSON variables and I have been trying to insert a timestamp in it.

This is my test table (`schema.mdummy`):

- `k` and `v` are varchars
- `n` is an integer
- `t` is a timestamp

I found out these statements work fine:

```
INSERT INTO mschema.MDUMMY (k, v) 
VALUES ((SELECT k FROM mschema.MDUMMY WHERE k LIKE 'xp3'), '33');

SELECT TIMESTAMP('1965-07-27', '15:30:00') + 59 SECONDS FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

But this one does not work as expected.

```
INSERT INTO mschema.MDUMMY (k, n, t) VALUES ( 
 '70', 
 70, 
 (SELECT TIMESTAMP('1965-07-27-15.30.00') + 59 SECONDS FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) 
);
```

Is it some error on the syntax or is it impossible to perform in DB2?

DB Server OS is the latest Fedora server.

Comment: What does it even mean: "does not work as expected"? What was expected? What happened instead? And why are you using a subselect to calculate the timestamp value?

Comment: Your statement should work fine, what error did you get? However, there are better ways to do it: `insert into mschema.MDUMMY (k, n, t) values ('870',70, TIMESTAMP('1965-07-27-15.30.00') + 59 SECONDS)`

Answer (score 1):

Following sequence of statements worked fine in Db2 (for LUW)

```
create table mschema.MDUMMY (k varchar(10), n int, t timestamp)

INSERT INTO mschema.MDUMMY (k, n, t) VALUES (   '70',   70,   (SELECT
TIMESTAMP('1965-07-27-15.30.00') + 59 SECONDS FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1) 
);

SELECT * FROM mschema.MDUMMY
```

I just copied the second statement from your question. 
This means you made some other mistake running it or you are maybe not running it on Db2 LUW - this is why it is always useful to specify the OS.

Comment: It is working now. Shout to @Lennart for simplifying the query.

Comment: Ok fine - but also your first try should have worked - this is what I tried to prove.

Comment: Don't really know why, but you're right. My once first solutions works now.